# I can't simplify this system of equation that uses ln(1/x). I am having trouble on how i can find the specific value of x

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Hi guys I need to solve for the specific value of x.

the given is $y = ln (\frac{1}{x}) $

I need to plug it in $\frac{1}{y}$ - $xe^y$ - $4y$ + $4y^2$ = $0$

I am having trouble with the algebra behind this system of equations. I would like to ask what steps do i need to take to solve for the value of x.

Comment: Solve for $y$.  Not $e^{y}=e^{\ln \frac 1x} = \frac 1x$ so $xe^y = x \frac 1x=1$ so if you solve for $y$ that is $\frac 1y -1 + 4y + 4y^2 = 0$.  When you solve for $y = K$ (where $K$ is the solutions to $\frac 1y -1 + 4y + 4y^2=0$) then $k=\ln \frac 1x$ so $\frac 1x = e^k$ so $x = \frac 1{e^K}$.

Comment: Yeah but what is the specific value of K? i need the values of x and y so i can solve for the critical points of a function of two variables

Comment: As pointed out by @fleablood $K$ is any solution of the equation $$\frac1y-1+4y+4y^2=0 \\ \implies 4y^3+4y^2-y+1=0$$ There are thus, $3$ possible values of $K$.

Comment: "Yeah but what is the specific value of K? "  Well, you have to do *SOME* work.  You asked the steps to take.  So I told you the steps to take.  So then equation $\frac 1y -1 + 4y + 4y^2 =0$ or in other words $4y^3 + 4y^2 - y+ 1=0$.  The rational root theorem (done in my head so I could have made a error) says there is not rational root so we'll have to use that cubic formula that every one hates.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, you need to solve for $y$ the cubic equation
$$4y^3+4y^2-y+1=0$$ If you follow the steps given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation), you will notice that there is only one real root since $\Delta=-944$.

Using the [hyperbolic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root)
$$y=-\frac{1}{3} \left(1+\sqrt{7} \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{44}{7
   \sqrt{7}}\right)\right)\right)$$ is the exact solution.

Comment: thank you!! i got it now